# How to suppress the product image?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

using the standard TwentyTwenty theme I've placed in my `functions.php` the following:

```php
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_show_product_images', 20);
```

expecting to remove the product image from product displays.  it doesn't seem to work (it works with one of the Rey themes but not with TwentyTwenty), though I can see in the `wc-template-hooks.php` (line 120), the following:

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_show_product_images', 20 );
```

help?

Answer (score 0):

ugh.  I'm editing the `functions.php` in a different theme